# Silverlight Dockpanel missing in toolbox

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have installed Silverlight3_tools and Silverlight_sdk and still unable to find DockPanel in the toolbox. Both the installers installed without asking for a save location. How do I find the reference now?

I am using VS 2008 SP1 on win XP sp2

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DockPanel` is found in the Silverlight Toolkit.  For Silverlight 3 you will need the [Nov09 Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/36060).